# Where do I ask questions about Stack Overflow Meta itself? Is there a Meta Meta?

Tags: support, meta, faq-proposed

For discussions about the policies and inner workings of Stack Overflow, we have Meta Stack Overflow. As described in the Help Center's ["What's Meta?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page:

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does.

But **where can I discuss the policies and inner workings of Meta Stack Overflow itself?**

Should I post them here on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), or on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), or on some entirely different site?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 19):

For questions about [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (this site) itself, you should:

1. Post the question here on Meta Stack Overflow, *and*
2. Tag your question with the [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag, as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta/info).

The global meta site, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), is used for support, feature requests, and bugs about the core engine powering [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) belonging to the Stack Exchange network. You should not ask about issues pertaining only to specific site there. Have a look at [What topics can you ask on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Note that it is perfectly fine to ask about network-wide issues on site-specific Meta sites like this one. For example, if you have a feature request for the core Stack Exchange engine, you can propose that *either* on Meta Stack Exchange *or* Meta Stack Overflow.